# How to redirect in htaccess with a wildcard

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wildcard

This is really bugging me, for something that should be real simple.

Trying to 301 redirect a URL (via htaccess) - in the following manner:

```
https://www.example.com/forums/sub-forum/index.php
```

needs to be redirected to:

```
https://www.example.com/forums/sub-forum/
```

Basically want to get rid of the index.php (note: the sub-forum is a wildcard, as it can be anything, e.g. football-forum or tennis-forum etc...)

So far I've managed to work out that I need to do something along these lines:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/forums/.*/index.php /forums/<wildcard>
```

However, I'm not sure what to put  in instead of `<wildcard>` part. I've tried putting `.*`, but that doesn't work

Any ideas on how to achieve this?  Your help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Okay, this is what I've managed to achieve thus far:   

RedirectMatch 301 ^/forums/.*/index.php /forums/wildcard

Comment: However, I'm not sure what to put in "wildcard" part above. I've tried .* but it doesn't work.